# C++ : AL/altypes.h No such file or directory

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I am trying to get started with OpenAL.

I am trying to compile this program which I got from [here](http://www.edenwaith.com/products/pige/tutorials/openal.php#compile) using:

```
g++ main.cpp -lOpenAL
```

At the moment the error `"AL/altypes.h" No such file or directory.` Appears. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I have installed `libopenal-dev`. (I am on Ubuntu 13.04 I think?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <AL/altypes.h>
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alu.h>
#include <AL/alut.h>


#define NUM_BUFFERS 1
#define NUM_SOURCES 1
#define NUM_ENVIRONMENTS 1

ALfloat listenerPos[] = {0.0, 0.0, 4.0};
ALfloat listenerVel[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
ALfloat listenerOri[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};

ALfloat source0Pos[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
ALfloat source0Vel[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

ALuint buffer[NUM_BUFFERS];
ALuint source[NUM_SOURCES];
ALuint environment[NUM_ENVIRONMENTS];

ALsizei size, freq;
ALenum format;
ALvoid* data;

void init(void)
{
    alListenerfv(AL_POSITION,listenerPos);
    alListenerfv(AL_VELOCITY,listenerVel);
    alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION,listenerOri);

    alGetError(); // clear any error messages

    // Generate buffers, or else no sound will happen!
    alGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, buffer);

    if(alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) 
    {
        std::cout << "- Error creating buffers !!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "init() - No errors yet." << std::endl;
    }

    alutLoadWAVFile((Albyte *) "c.wav", &format, &data, size,&freq, &al_bool);
    alBufferData(buffer[0],format,data,size,freq);
    alutUnloadWAV(format,data,size,freq);

    alGetError(); /* clear error */
    alGenSources(NUM_SOURCES, source);

    if(alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) 
    {
        std::cout << "- Error creating sources !!" << std::endl;
        exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "init - no errors after alGenSources" << std::endl;
    }

    alSourcef(source[0], AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
    alSourcef(source[0], AL_GAIN, 1.0f);
    alSourcefv(source[0], AL_POSITION, source0Pos);
    alSourcefv(source[0], AL_VELOCITY, source0Vel);
    alSourcei(source[0], AL_BUFFER,buffer[0]);
    alSourcei(source[0], AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);
}

int main()
{

    //initialise openAL
    alutInit(&argc, argv) ; 

    init();

    return 0;
}
```

As an aside, this program won't actually do what I want at the moment.

I want to declare an array of double/int, populate it with data and play that data. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a package  libalut-dev    which contains utilities, however take a look at libsndfile for audio file I/O.   Its always a holy grail to roll your own WAV / PCM parser which teaches you a lot and its not too difficult. WRT your aside ...the following openal code synthesizes data into an openal buffer then renders it as audio.  Another page of code beyond below will get you a streaming audio player which is nice to have handy.   compile it using

```
gcc -o gen_tone_08  gen_tone_08.c -lopenal -lm
```

Let us know how you get on

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    // gives malloc
#include <math.h>


#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenAL/al.h>
#include <OpenAL/alc.h>
#elif __linux
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#endif

ALCdevice  * openal_output_device;
ALCcontext * openal_output_context;

ALuint internal_buffer;
ALuint streaming_source[1];

int al_check_error(const char * given_label) {

    ALenum al_error;
    al_error = alGetError();

    if(AL_NO_ERROR != al_error) {

        printf("ERROR - %s  (%s)\n", alGetString(al_error), given_label);
        return al_error;
    }
    return 0;
}

void MM_init_al() {

    const char * defname = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);

    openal_output_device  = alcOpenDevice(defname);
    openal_output_context = alcCreateContext(openal_output_device, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(openal_output_context);

    // setup buffer and source

    alGenBuffers(1, & internal_buffer);
    al_check_error("failed call to alGenBuffers");
}

void MM_exit_al() {

    ALenum errorCode = 0;

    // Stop the sources
    alSourceStopv(1, & streaming_source[0]);        //      streaming_source
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < 1; ++ii) {
        alSourcei(streaming_source[ii], AL_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    // Clean-up
    alDeleteSources(1, &streaming_source[0]);
    alDeleteBuffers(16, &streaming_source[0]);
    errorCode = alGetError();
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    errorCode = alGetError();
    alcDestroyContext(openal_output_context);
    alcCloseDevice(openal_output_device);
}

void MM_render_one_buffer() {

    /* Fill buffer with Sine-Wave */
    // float freq = 440.f;
    float freq = 100.f;
    float incr_freq = 0.1f;

    int seconds = 4;
    // unsigned sample_rate = 22050;
    unsigned sample_rate = 44100;
    double my_pi = 3.14159;
    size_t buf_size = seconds * sample_rate;

    short * samples = malloc(sizeof(short) * buf_size);

   printf("\nhere is freq %f\n", freq);
    int i=0;
    for(; i<buf_size; ++i) {
        samples[i] = 32760 * sin( (2.f * my_pi * freq)/sample_rate * i );

        freq += incr_freq;
        // incr_freq += incr_freq;
        // freq *= factor_freq;

        if (100.0 > freq || freq > 5000.0) {

            incr_freq *= -1.0f;
        }
    }

    /* upload buffer to OpenAL */
    alBufferData( internal_buffer, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, samples, buf_size, sample_rate);
    al_check_error("populating alBufferData");

    free(samples);

    /* Set-up sound source and play buffer */
    // ALuint src = 0;
    // alGenSources(1, &src);
    // alSourcei(src, AL_BUFFER, internal_buffer);
    alGenSources(1, & streaming_source[0]);
    alSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_BUFFER, internal_buffer);
    // alSourcePlay(src);
    alSourcePlay(streaming_source[0]);

    // ---------------------

    ALenum current_playing_state;
    alGetSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_SOURCE_STATE, & current_playing_state);
    al_check_error("alGetSourcei AL_SOURCE_STATE");

    while (AL_PLAYING == current_playing_state) {

        printf("still playing ... so sleep\n");

        sleep(1);   // should use a thread sleep NOT sleep() for a more responsive finish

        alGetSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_SOURCE_STATE, & current_playing_state);
        al_check_error("alGetSourcei AL_SOURCE_STATE");
    }

    printf("end of playing\n");

    /* Dealloc OpenAL */
    MM_exit_al();

}   //  MM_render_one_buffer

int main() {

    MM_init_al();

    MM_render_one_buffer();
}
```